# binary search maximum depth exceeded

Tags: python

Impementing binary search using python. It is showing maximum depth exceeded.

```
def binary(arr,l,h,x):
    if h>=l:
        mid=(h-l)//2
        if arr[mid]==x:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid]>x:
            return binary(arr,l,mid-1,x)
        else:
            return binary(arr,mid+1,h,x)
    else:
        return -1

arr=[1,5,6,8,3,9]
x=8
result=binary(arr,0,len(arr)-1,x)
if result!=-1:
    print("ele present at %d" % result)
else:
    print("element not present")
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: binary search only makes sense for sorted arrays. Also `(h-l)//2` is wrong.

Comment: I changed to l+(h-l)//2 . It is showing element not present.what I should use here?

Comment: please can you explain what your code does.

Comment: If you share the logic then I will post the correct answer. Currently I am struggling to figure out what your program does

Comment: 1.finding mid element in the array 2. if mid element is greater than element to be found we go to the first half of array and now h becomes mid-1. again finding mid element and same process goes 3. if mid< than element we take second half.

Comment: actually I missed one thing. binary search works for sorted array only right?

Comment: @SnegaS I solved the problem. Please check the answer. I edited it

Answer (score -1):

```
from functools import lru_cache
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def binary(arr, l, h, x):
    if h >= l:
        mid = round((h + l) / 2)
        if arr[mid] == x:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] > x:
            return binary(arr, l, mid - 1, x)
        else:
            return binary(arr, mid + 1, h, x)
    else:
        return -1

arr = (1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9)
x = 8
result = binary(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, x)

if result != -1:
    print("ele present at %d" % result)
else:
    print("element not present")
```

This error is caused due to limited recursion depth in python. So with this line `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)` we set the recursion depth to 10000. `lru_cache` stores previous recursion results in cache memory so that the `binary()` function doesn't have to calculate the same result again and again.
Also, use array as tuple, not as a list. Because list can throw `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. And change `mid = (h - l) // 2` to  `mid = round((h + l) / 2)`. You code then runs fine.

**Output**

```
ele present at 4
```